# Satellites traveling in single file across the sky

Tags: satellite, identify-this-object

I just watched 46 (best count) satellites traveling in single file, about 3 second intervals between them. Is that possible?  I don't want to believe they were UFO's.  Time was `06:20 ET`

Answer (score 2):

In January SpaceX launched into space a string of 60 satellites into space. These are satellites for internet communications. Astronomers say the proliferation of the bright metallic satellites could seriously degrade the night view, interfering with both optical and radio astronom$y^1$

1.https://www.sciencealert.com/spacex-just-launched-a-third-batch-of-its-starlink-satellites

Could this be what you saw?  I don't know, I'm just saying this is maybe the case.